# Next line after while loop not executed

Tags: java, filestream, printstream

I am trying to write contents to a file, but once the while loop prints all the lines , it get's stuck and doesn't go to the next line.  The line after while loop are not being executed. My first guess was that maybe the fstream is still waiting for another line, but the while loop does check if no more data then it should come out.

Please help me out here !
Thanks.

//Code

```
File file;

                DataInputStream inputData = new DataInputStream(newPeerConnection.getInputStream());

                file = new File(
                        "F:\\Workspace\\PeerToPeer\\src\\ncsu\\csc\\socketClasses\\out\\out.txt");

                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                PrintWriter fstream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
                        file, true));

                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                                 System.out.println("Writing to file: ");
                while ((strval = inputData.readUTF()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strval);
                    fstream.println(strval);
                    //fstream.flush();
                    //fstream.close();
                }
                //These lines are not executed
                System.out.println("Do you want to download another file (Y/N)?");
                wantToContinue = scannerObj.next();
                 out.writeUTF(wantToContinue);
                 out.flush();}
```

Comment: If they aren't executed, either your loop is infinite or it is blocked.

Comment: the loop is not infinite, else the values "null" would keep printing after the data of the file was read. It might be blocked, but am not sure how.

Comment: It's most likely blocked, please post the code that writes to the stream.

Comment: Also, set a timeout on your stream, that way you get an exception in cases like these instead of a dead application.

Comment: I tried finding the documentation for readUTF for timeout, but that doesn't have the information init. Also surprisingly it doesn't mention readUTF is a blocking call. This is what i referred to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF()

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `while` loop is blocked by `inputData.readUTF()`.

You should ensure the input stream of `newPeerConnection` is closed by another port, otherwise `inputData` will wait for next input and `inputData.readUTF()` blocks.

Comment: Yes you're correct, i figured readUTF() was a blocking call . I am trying readLine(), but that's deprecated i believe.